# How to check if LogWriter has been set?

Tags: c#, logging, exception, enterprise-library-6

I am trying to handle an Enterprise Library 6 LogWriter Exception that has recently popped up after upgrading from Enterprise Library 4 to 6.

I either get:

> The LogWriter has not been set for the Logger static class. Set it
>   invoking the Logger.SetLogWriter method.

OR

> The LogWriter is already set.

...depending on the scenario.

The problem is that it throws an `InvalidOperationException` which seems too generic to handle, and that even checking using

```
if (Logger.Writer == null)
```

... also yields an exception, **so how would one then check if the writer is set or not?**

Comment: Sounds like you're supposed ensure it is set exactly once instead of testing the property. Why does that not work?

Comment: [this](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/442089) seems to handle your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and comments.

I have looked through the project's code and seen that there is nothing built into it that supports this.

Even though the project is no longer under development, I took a chance and posted a [feature request](https://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/33863).

Best scenario to achieve this requirement would <s>be forking</s> downloading it and adding logic that does a check and additionally defining specific exceptions (see feature request):

`LogWriterNotSetException` and `LogWriterAlreadySetException`

**EDIT**

Struck out forking as that would have licensing implications. Ownership has not been transfered for the Logging Application Block. [Only Unity and Prism have been transferred](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/03/19/prism-grows-up.aspx).

According to a [comment on the notice about the future of Unity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/#comment-111155), from a P & P member:

> For the Logging Application Block, we consider it to be superceded by
>   Semantic Logging (formerly Semantic Logging Application Block or
>   SLAB).
>
> https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging
>
> In other words, we do not intend to work on the Logging Application
>   Block and we have no plan to transfer it to new owners.

So best bet for anyone working on something new is trying out [Semantic Logging](https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging)

Answer (score 6):

According to [this CodePlex discussion](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/442089),

> The boostrapping behavior of Enterprise Library has changed in Version 6. The impact for the static Logger facade is that you need to set the internal `LogWriter` (for example at application start)

If you're in a web application scenario, `Application_Start()` is the good way to do so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create());
}
```

Otherwise, set things up in `Main()` method (or somewhere around it -- say, during container initialization).

Comment: This is the way to go. If you set it once here, there should be no question on whether or not it was set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesnt answer the question.